# Setting a minimum QDate with todays date

Tags: python, pyqt4, qdate

I'm trying to set the minimum date for a QDate box to todays date. I keep getting a syntax. I have set the format which works fine, but the minimum date won't work.

```
    self.ui.CreateStuDOB.setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
    self.ui.CreateStuDOB.setMinimumDate(QDate::currentDate())
```

Returned error

self.ui.CreateStuDOB.setMinimumDate(QDate::currentDate())
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks in advance

Comment: That `::` is C++ syntax - always use `.` in PyQt.

Comment: I know that was stupid sorry!!! I have changed it now but it still isn't working it's saying that 'QDate' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

Firstly I used the correct Python syntax instead of the C++ syntax as pointed out by ekhumoro.

```
self.ui.CreateStuDOB.setMinimumDate(QDate.currentDate())
```

Then I correctly imported QDate using:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
```